# spark whole text file - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: exception, apache-spark, out-of-memory

Trying to read large text files (file > 4GB) using sc.wholeTextFiles().

Running into java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.

```
>>       at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.hugeCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:123)
>>       at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:117)
>>       at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
>>       at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)
>>       at org.spark-project.guava.io.ByteStreams.copy(ByteStreams.java:211)
>>       at org.spark-project.guava.io.ByteStreams.toByteArray(ByteStreams.java:252)
>>       at org.apache.spark.input.WholeTextFileRecordReader.nextKeyValue(WholeTextFileRecordReader.scala:83)
>>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileRecordReader.nextKeyValue(CombineFileRecordReader.java:69)
>>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(NewHadoopRDD.scala:143)
>>       at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)
>>       at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getIteratorSize(Utils.scala:1467)
>>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1006)
>>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1006)
>>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1498)
>>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1498)
>>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
>>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
>>       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:203)
>>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Java applications are allowed to use only a limited amount of memory, the Java heap space error or the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` is thrown whenever the JVM reaches the heap size limit.

The default heap size limit is 1G but the limit can be extended by passing JVM the parameters -Xmx.

You can extend it to 4G by:

```
java -Xmx4g
```